# FFMPEG max filesize limits

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a file size max for processing video files with ffmpeg. I have software running `ffmpeg` via cron job. It processes files under 300MB but above that it doesn't seem to process the files.

Comment: Maybe. But is sure isn't around 300 MB. Even videos shot on a phone would easily exceed that.

Comment: Is spliting a large video an opton? You could use -segment_time 00:05:00 to split a large video in 5 min parts for example....

Comment: what if you run it manually - then you may be able to see the issue